# How to pass data between two ViewControllers with TabBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a tab bar class (that is attached to my tab bar controller), Like so:

```
class CaptionTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

  func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    var logView = self.viewControllers![2] as CaptionsController
    logView.log.append("test working!")
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.delegate = self;
  }
}
```

---

And my receiving viewcontroller is like this:

```
class CaptionsController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var captionSearchBar: UISearchBar!
 @IBOutlet weak var captionsTitle: UILabel!
 var receiveImage:UIImage!
 var receiveCategoryText:String!
 var log = [String]()

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  println(log)
 }
}
```

---

This works when I'm explicitly setting `logView.log` in `CaptionTabBarController`.

The result I get in my output windows is as expected. Each tabbar item I click adds "test working!" to the array.

My question is:

**How would I be able to get a value from another viewcontroller class to `CaptionsController` using the `tabBarController` method I am employing?**

This view is a part of a "child" of the tabbar itself, so I'm assuming it already has an instance. All examples I've found just show this, but not how to get data from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIViewController` that wants to pass the data can store it on your `AppDelegate` class. Then the `UITabBarController` delegate method can pull it off and set properties on the receiving `UIViewController`.

Also, assuming your app is based on the Tab Controller, your AppDelegate can find it with `window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController`.

Comment: Honestly. I'm trying to come to terms with some fundamental concepts in swift as I've just started developing in such an environment (no objective-c experience). I'm not entirely sure how to use the `AppDelegate` class and how to pull things off of it in `UITabBarController`.

Comment: @fred02138 more details?